# How to apply a function with argument to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove all accents in the data. I found a function but I am not able to apply the same on entire dataframe at once.

```
import unicodedata
import pandas as pd

def remove_accents(input_str):
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nfkd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii


data = {'name': ['Guzmán', 'Molly'],
        'year': [2012, 2012]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

How can I apply the above function?

Is there any parameter in pandas `read_csv` that I can use to achieve similar output?

Comment: Have you looked at any examples of `apply`? Your case looks very straigtfoward. And I do not understand your last question entirely.

Comment: Try the [`apply` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: giving error as `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)` expects two patameters

Comment: `df.name.apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ASCII', 'ignore'))`

Comment: @COLDSPEED, thanks but I get `TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be unicode, not str` eror. Also, I need to do it on the entire data frame all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is pretty straightforward:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(remove_accents)
```

Also, in case you are using Python 3, I would recommend changing the last line of your `remove_accents` function. `only_ascii` is returning binary data, and it's usually best practice to keep unicode text as regular (Python 3) `str`.

```
def remove_accents(input_str):
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nfkd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @Thanks. Is there a way I can apply the function on entire dataframe instead of doing it one column at a time?

Comment: You can loop over the columns or try something like: `df.apply(lambda x: [remove_accents(i) for i in x])`. Probably not very efficient, but gets the job done.

Comment: Btw, a good way to "debug" `apply` and understand what your function is taking as input is passing a function that just simply prints the input it receives: `lambda x: print(x)`. Probably Python 3 only though.